# Why is my discord bot in node.js showing error on }?

Tags: node.js

I am creating a new discord bot using node.js and I have an error which I don't understand why.
To see the whole code visit:
https://repl.it/@Make_True/ShortMinigames-discord-bot

I am new to programming so I have no idea what is wrong with it.

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === 'What is ShortMinigames?') {
message.channel.send({
  embed: {
    "title": "What is ShortMinigames?",
    "description": "ShortMinigames is a Minecraft minigames server currently Offline for the public. We are currently planning to release PVP, Bedwars, Skywars, Parkour, Capture the Flag and build battle.",
    "color": 6334225,
    "timestamp": "2019-05-11T07:06:44.314Z",
    "footer": {
      "icon_url": "https://i.ibb.co/WVXy4rJ/Short-Minigameslogo.png",
      "text": "ShortMinigames"
    },
    "thumbnail": {
      "url": "https://i.ibb.co/WVXy4rJ/Short-Minigameslogo.png"
    },
    "author": {
      "name": "Written by: Make True",
      "icon_url": "https://i.ibb.co/5xFvYK3/j-k-p.png"
    },
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "What version is ShortMinigames running on?",
        "value": "Currently we are on minecraft 1.14."
      },
      {
        "name": "How can I apply for staff/builder?",
        "value": "To apply use the command -apply in #:computer:commands, also to find out more information about applying for staff/builder."
      },
      {
        "name": "What is the server IP?",
        "value": "Sorry but we are still offline for the public. The server ip will be released to the public as we finally come online"
      },
      {
        "name": "Any more questions?",
        "value": "If you have any questions then please ask them in #:sos:support and we will try to answer it as quickly and accurately as possible. Thank you for your understanding and your patience and we hope to see you soon!"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: And what is this error your talking about ?

Comment: It looks like you are missing the closing `)` for the `.send` method. You'll also need to add the closing `}` and `)` for the `if` and the `client.on` method. Look at the lines in the online editor. It gives you clues where the closing characters should be

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close  `)` of the `send` command, same for the `}` and the `)` of the `if` statement, and you forgot the `}` of the `client.on` method.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'What is ShortMinigames?') {
  message.channel.send({
    embed: {
      "title": "What is ShortMinigames?",
      "description": "ShortMinigames is a Minecraft minigames server currently Offline for the public. We are currently planning to release PVP, Bedwars, Skywars, Parkour, Capture the Flag and build battle.",
      "color": 6334225,
      "timestamp": "2019-05-11T07:06:44.314Z",
      "footer": {
        "icon_url": "https://i.ibb.co/WVXy4rJ/Short-Minigameslogo.png",
        "text": "ShortMinigames"
      },
      "thumbnail": {
        "url": "https://i.ibb.co/WVXy4rJ/Short-Minigameslogo.png"
      },
      "author": {
        "name": "Written by: Make True",
        "icon_url": "https://i.ibb.co/5xFvYK3/j-k-p.png"
      },
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "What version is ShortMinigames running on?",
          "value": "Currently we are on minecraft 1.14."
        },
        {
          "name": "How can I apply for staff/builder?",
          "value": "To apply use the command -apply in #:computer:commands, also to find out more information about applying for staff/builder."
        },
        {
          "name": "What is the server IP?",
          "value": "Sorry but we are still offline for the public. The server ip will be released to the public as we finally come online"
        },
        {
          "name": "Any more questions?",
          "value": "If you have any questions then please ask them in #:sos:support and we will try to answer it as quickly and accurately as possible. Thank you for your understanding and your patience and we hope to see you soon!"
        }
      ]
    }
  })
}})
```